# Почему сортировка пузырьком работает некоректно?

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, сортировка, python-3.6

```py
def comparasion(a, b):
return a > b

def bubble_sort(array):
    for j in range(len(array)-1):
        for i in range(len(array)-1):
            if comparasion(array[i][0], array[i+1][0]):
                array[i], array[i+1] = array[i+1], array[i]
    return array

array = input().split()
print(bubble_sort(array))
```

Если ввести:

```
1 10 44 33 27 9 99 11 34
```

, то выводит:

```
['1', '10', '11', '27', '33', '34', '44', '9', '99']
```

, а не:

```
['1','9', '10', '11', '27', '33', '34', '44', '99']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Python 3.x функция `input()` всегда возвращает строку. После разбивки строки при помощи `str.split()` вы получаете список **строк**.

Строки во всех известных мне языках программирования сравниваются [лексикографически](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA). Т.е. берем первый символ обоих строк и сравниваем его - если симаолы равны идем дальше, если нет - сразу возвращаем результат сравнения первых символов.

Пример:

```
print('9' > '10000')
>>> True
```

Т.е. если сравнить строки `'9'` и `'10000'` - `9` окажется больше т.к. для первых символов: `'9' > '1'`, после чего сравнение прекращается.

---

Чтобы исправить ситуацию, преобразуйте список строк в список чисел:

```
array = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

или в функциональном стиле:

```
array = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

---

Также у вас не совсем правильно работает сама функция сортировки. Вот исправленная и немного оптимизированная версия:

```
def bubble_sort(array):
    arr = array.copy()
    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(n-1):
        for j in range(0, n-i-1):
            if arr[j] > arr[j+1] :
                arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j+1], arr[j]
    return arr
```

Comment: У автора ещё и `j` никак не используется, из-за чего алгоритм в 2 раза больше вычислений делает, чем нужно

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо! Добавил исправленную версию)